# AVPlayer crashing in StitchedStreamPlayer example when playing audio

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avplayer, avplayerlayer

The [StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) in Apple's documentation gives an example of how to stream video on the iphone. 
The example works fine for the example video given. However, if instead of a video, a link to an audio file is provided, such as [this](http://files.parse.com/ec0335d6-135b-418a-a5d0-3f697be04c70/ef948998-570e-4ca3-9d07-a5399165fecb-mxK2x03TK7.caf), the app crashes with the following assert, which seems to be coming from an assert of internal framework files.

To reproduce: 
On an iOS 6 device, in `Settings`:`Developer`:`Network Link Conditioner` - Status:ON/Very Bad Network
Once the AVPlayerLayer is visible (it will be a black box since there is no video, only audio), press the play button and slide the scrubber.

> 2013-06-08 00:00:20.679 StitchedStreamPlayer[3979:907] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[AVPlayerPeriodicCaller initWithPlayer:interval:queue:block:],
>   /SourceCache/EmbeddedAVFoundation/EmbeddedAVFoundation-461.12/Fig/AVPlayer.m:3993
>
> 2013-06-08 00:00:27.464 StitchedStreamPlayer[3979:907] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying:
>   CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(interval, >, kCMTimeZero)'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x32a802a3 0x3a72597f 0x32a8015d 0x33355ab7 0x31bc18e5 0x31bbf5d1 0xb4931 0x349730c5 0x34973077
>   0x34973055 0x3497290b 0x34972e01 0x3489b5f1 0x34888801 0x3488811b
>   0x3658b5a3 0x32a55683 0x32a54ee9 0x32a53cb7 0x329c6ebd 0x329c6d49
>   0x3658a2eb 0x348dc301 0xb37d9 0xb3770) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS uptil 6.1. Fixed in iOS 7.

**Bug ID 14099611: AVPlayer crashing in StitchedStreamPlayer example when playing audio**

Comment: i am still facing this issue in iOS 7

Comment: @007- I haven't faced this problem in a long time since iOS 7. If you are really facing this bug, you can reopen the bug referenced above with Apple.

Comment: Actually I was facing this problem is iOS 7, I don't know what was the reason but now I have changed my code.